# Obtaining Pairs of Consecutive Elements with Conditional Adjustment

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, design-patterns

I've encountered a particular problem and was wondering if anyone has any insights on how to approach it more efficiently or elegantly.

To be accurate, given the list:

```
list = {2, 5, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 31};
```

I'm looking to generate pairs of consecutive elements in the following manner:

> {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {6, 8}, {9, 12}, {13, 16}, {17, 20}, {21, 24}, {25,
> 28}, {29, 31}}

Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
Table[{If[i == 1, 0, list[[i - 1]]] + 1, list[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@list}]
```

The above code works, but I'm interested in knowing if there is a more elegant or efficient way to achieve the same result.

I would appreciate any suggestions or alternative approaches anyone in the community may have. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {2, 5, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 31};
res = {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {6, 8}, {9, 12}, {13, 16}, {17, 20}, {21, 
   24}, {25, 28}, {29, 31}};

listplusone = Most[1 + # & /@ {0}~Join~list]
Transpose[{listplusone, list}] == res
```

> True

Comment: (+1) Nicely done, @Syed! I'll just wait for at least one more answer to make a comparison with yours, and then accept the answer. :-)

Comment: `listplusone = Most[1 + {0}~Join~list]` would also be okay.

Comment: The suggested change looks very elegant: `Transpose[{Most[1 + {0}~Join~#], #}] &@list`

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {2, 5, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 31};
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[Prepend[list, 0], {a_, b_} :> {a + 1, b}, Overlaps -> True]
```

{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {6, 8}, {9, 12}, {13, 16}, {17, 20}, {21, 24}, {25,
28}, {29, 31}}

Comment: (+1) Your solution is also very nice, @eldo, because I like using the functions dedicated to sequences. :-)